# Code analysis: check if method is called by a specific class

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a huge C# + VB.NET solution that has about 210 projects.

Some developers have over time been using a method that only work in a specific context (HttpContext needs to be present) which means that Console Applications that somewhere in their calltree use this method, will fail.

Other than throwing an exception (which might break running solutions), is there a way to check if this context dependent method is called by a specific 'parent' ?

In Visual Studio it's possible to "Find All References", so i'm looking for some tool that could do this recursively to give me a list of eg: all projects that somehow call this broken code.

Comment: Why you don't fix this method by checking if the `HttpContext` is available? It seems that throwing an exception in that case is not the right way to handle it. Maybe log this and then return. The other question is why your console applications use methods that rely on the `HttpContext`. I guess the better way (which breaks your code) was to pass it to the method as parameter.

Comment: The method already does that. The problem is that it returns empty string when it's not available - which kind of makes it fail softly.

Comment: I think you are looking for a Call Graph and Dependency Graph - https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph